# I can't get jquery preventDefault to work for my parallax slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

-EDIT-

After hours upon hours upon hours of online html/css/js courses, youtube vids, browsing through stackoverflow, endless toiling in notepad++, and what not, I've done it!
https://studiodevana.000webhostapp.com/index.html

All in all it's pretty close to the desired outcome. However, atm some minor stumbling blocks remain:
1) AJAX.
I can't get the initial transition from index to the navigation page to work through Ajax. Tried doing what the example at w3schools said, but to no avail.
The current situation is a bit wonky, but acceptable (change current page opacity to 0 from 1, white flash, load new page background color, load new page background image, load new page background images/rest, change opacity to 1 from 0).
What I'd like to accomplish through AJAX:
-click on link to navigation page
-prevent default/stay on current page and wait
-load/render next page
-once next page is completely loaded/rendered, start changing opacity of current page from 1 to 0
  -SIMULTANEOUSLY start changing opacity from next page from 0 to 1
-once these animations are completed, unload first page
I've tried searching for this functionality but can't find a description anywhere...
2) Content slides slide in indented vertically.Once a content slide is slid onto the screen, the text is indented downwards about 5%. Changing the contentpage divs positions to "fixed" seems to be the only fix, but with a "position:fixed", the page becomes unscrollable, which is undesired.
3) Google Map in "contact" section.
The Google Map in the "contact" section sometimes fails to load, and only loads after a page refresh. This might be due to my free webhost which I use for page testing...but maybe it's in the JS? I make it work through an external JS file by adding "async defer" to the API key in the html file.
4) Opacity animation. The ".animate({opacity: 0.3}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'});" only works when used with 'slow'. When I assign a value to it, say "500", it breaks. It will change the opacity, but once the animation is complete, the opacity will instantly return to the initial value, and STAY there. Ergo when you activate the animation again, the opacity is and stays at 1, no matter what you click.

-EDIT-

I've embarked on making a mobile website, and have settled on the "parallax slideshow" for page transitions.
Here's my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j7bwnbwm/9/

As you can see, my preventDefault is not working, even though no errors are showing up. I've tried applying it to to all known ids, classes, and what not, but the slideshow keeps scrolling to the top once you click the arrow.
I want the index page to retain either its original scroll position, or similar position to the next slideshow element (if indeed they are linked and behave like one element, which I'm not sure of).
I'm a novice when it comes to webpage developing, only having written my first line of html ever 5 days ago, and this is giving me a serious headache all day. I suspect the radio buttons can't be targetted with this method, but am nowhere near knowledgable enough to figure out a solution.

```
  <body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="sp-slideshow">

    <input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label>

    <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" />
    <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>

    <input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-3" />
    <label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label>

    <input id="button-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-4" />
    <label for="button-4" class="button-label-4"></label>

    <input id="button-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-5" />
    <label for="button-5" class="button-label-5"></label>

    <label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label>
    <label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label>
    <label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>
    <label for="button-4" class="sp-arrow sp-a4"></label>
    <label for="button-5" class="sp-arrow sp-a5"></label>

    <div class="sp-content">
      <div class="sp-parallax-bg"></div>
      <ul class="sp-slider clearfix">
        <li>
          <img src="https://studiodevana.000webhostapp.com/images/image1.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="image01" />
        </li>
        <li>
          1st Page, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc.
        </li>
        <li>
          2nd page
        </li>
        <li>
          3rd page
        </li>
        <li>
          4th page
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script>
  src = "js/parallaxscript.js"

</script>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the `js/parallaxscript.js` in the fiddle. This is where the javascript/jquery side of the slideshow is handled right? Could you post it please?

Comment: the js box is literally all the js that's in the parallaxscript.js. I've only added it for the sake of getting the page reset/scroll to top to stop happening when you click the radio buttons. The slideshow is entirely CSS.

Comment: Alright, thank  you. Back to searching! :)

Comment: Congratulations on your progress. Regarding your new edits. Is the index and navigation pages 2 completely different pages?

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah they are completely seperate HTML files. Considering how the entire project is about 240KB after compression, making it all a one-page website would be possible, but afaik that's not the "correct" way to make a website.

Comment: Regarding your google maps issue. You'd have to do more debugging to find out where the issue is. The "Content slides slide in indented vertically.", again it's more debugging. This could be related to lingering whitespace, css, the content itself. As for the `animate` function... I am not particularly familiar with JQuery; so, it's hard for me to say much on complex problems with JQuery.

Comment: Also, the website link you posted... Is that your "development" server?

Comment: Gonna try and mess around with the css more to solve the indentation issue. And yeah, the website is my "development" server. It's quite buggy, but all in all quite decent considering it's absolutely free.

Comment: PS: Gonna see if I can pull off your second route for the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

You seem to be misunderstanding where and when to use AJAX. You said you are trying to use AJAX to navigate from 1 HTML Document to another HTML Document. This is **NOT** the correct usage of AJAX.

AJAX at a basic level is as following:

- AJAX is a means to bring in new content into a page without reloading
  the page.
- AJAX should be used when you do not want to reload the page; but, you
  have to communicate with your server.

In order to navigate from your index page to your navigation page there are two routes to take.

1. Use a link. A simple html `<a>`. This will reload the page.
2. Convert your navigation and index page into slides for your slideshow. This shouldn't reload the page if you use AJAX.

---

The `preventDefault` function is used to prevent default behavior for certain elements.

For example, when you click on a link. It's default behavior is to send the user to the address defined by the `href` attribute.

You can stop this behavior by using `preventDefault` in the click event of the link.

---

In order to maintain the scroll position, you will have to somehow save the scroll position when you click on the button and then reset on the new slide. This might cause some flicker or a brief moment where the new slide is at the top of the page and then gets scrolled down to the saved value.

It may be possible to make keeping the scroll position automated by using [background-position-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-x). Do note, this is an experimental css property. The basic support does not look that bad; but, do be wary of using it.

I believe the exact cause of your problem is your use of `background-position`. Since you set the value width and height value, I think it's setting the scroll position to the top of the screen.

---

In all honesty, how you have set up your slideshow is very complex and extremely inflexible.

I would suggest bring in more JavaScript and possibly asynchronous loading in the data. In order to bring in asynchronous you would need a server. You don't need to buy one, you can set free local development server. Essentially, it's a web-server that can only be accessed locally.

An asynchronous slideshow would essentially get the slides as they are needed.

E.X:

1. Load slide 1
2. User clicks next button. Get slide 2 from server.
3. Received slide 2 from server, get rid of slide 1 and display slide 2.
4. User clicks next button. Get slide 3 from server.
5. Received slide 3 from server, get rid of slide 2 and display slide 3.
6. User clicks previous button. Get slide 2 from server.
7. Received slide 2 from server, get rid of slide 3 and display slide 2.

As you see in this example, whenever the user clicks the next or previous button the website will ask the server for the appropriate slide. Once the website has gotten the slide from the server, it will replace the current slide with the new slide.

Note, this is an ASYNCHRONOUS slideshow. The page is NOT reloaded every time the user clicks the next or previous button. Only the slide is reloaded.

JQuery in particular is an asynchronous library. You can also keep this to pure JavaScript with the AJAX api.

A JavaScript (synchronous) slide show has many approaches.

- You could load all the slides and control visibility.
- You could also hold the contents of the slide in variables and just
  set the `innerHTML` property of the slide element.
- You could also setup a parallax slideshow by using JavaScript to change css classes. I personally would go for one of the other options. Having a css class for every slide is not maintainable.

All these options would have the same general idea where JavaScript would keep track of the current slide number and use that to determine what slide to display when the user clicks on previous or next.

Learning JavaScript or getting a local development server for an asynchronous slideshow might sound like a lot, and it is. Even with all the all-in-package local development server around. Despite the work, it will make your code a lot more readable and easy to comprehend.

It might be hard at first; however, once you have gotten some experience. You will be able to look back and realize how much more flexible and cool the JavaScript way is.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems I'll have to get into learning js more than I anticipated. At this point js still looks like mumbo jumbo to me, so there's a long way ahead. The parallax css is something I got from a free demo, thinking it would be easy to manipulate, but appearantly it's not that easy...

Comment: @Svarog If you need help with the JS, feel free to come back here. You should be able to edit your original post and append on your JavaScript attempt. I wouldn't rewrite the entire post though.

Comment: Lo and behold: https://studiodevana.000webhostapp.com/index.html I took your advice and learned some rudimentary JS. Rewrote the entire project from scratch, this time coming up with everything myself instead of copy-pasting demo projects. Some Jquery lines took me literally days to figure out how to write their syntax, even though I knew what I had in mind. Nevertheless, you were right, it's better to handle this through JS. After condensing, it boiled down to exactly 8 Jquery instructions to create the parallax effect, not bad! :-) Thanks for the helpful advice! PS: changed my original post.